# How do you store seed phrases for multiple wallets?

Tags: security, wallet

Let's say you have not just a hardware wallet but multiple software wallets. How do you store your seed phrases? Steel plates are a good solution but often a headache to stamp and store.

Has anyone figured out an easier, more effective solution? Paper wallets are great but then you run the risk of losing it all in a fire.

Answer (score 1):

> Paper wallets are great but then you run the risk of losing it all in a fire.

Storing photocopies in more than one geographic location mitigates that risk significantly.

An alternative *digital* solution is to store all your seeds in a single text file encrypted and uploaded to multiple online locations. That way you just have to remember one password to decrypt your text file with all your seeds.

You could even use one of the many single/one password tools / services.

In my opinion, digital (so encrypted backups), hands down beats any paper / physical versions.